# Client Missing Partials Error (Discord.js)

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, node-modules, discord-buttons

I tried importing a project into my own project. I got such an error.

```
C:\Users\iyild\OneDrive\Masaüstü\PattisBey-main\bot.js:6
      Partials.Message,
               ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Message')
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\iyild\OneDrive\Masaüstü\PattisBey-main\bot.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

should i load this partials ( i dont know what is the parial ) maybe it is a module? and how can i install it? im new in discord.js

```
const {PermissionsBitField, EmbedBuilder, ButtonStyle, Client, GatewayIntentBits, ChannelType, Partials, ActionRowBuilder, SelectMenuBuilder, ModalBuilder, TextInputBuilder, TextInputStyle, InteractionType, SelectMenuInteraction, ButtonBuilder } = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./config.js");
const db = require("croxydb")
const client = new Client({
    partials: [
      Partials.Message, 
      Partials.Channel, 
      Partials.GuildMember, 
      Partials.Reaction, 
      Partials.GuildScheduledEvent,
      Partials.User, 
      Partials.ThreadMember, 
    ],
    intents: [
      GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, 
      GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers, 
      GatewayIntentBits.GuildBans, 
      GatewayIntentBits.GuildEmojisAndStickers,
      GatewayIntentBits.GuildIntegrations,
      GatewayIntentBits.GuildWebhooks, 
      GatewayIntentBits.GuildInvites,
      GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates, 
      GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences, 
      GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
      GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions, 
      GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageTyping, 
      GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages, 
      GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageReactions, 
      GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageTyping, 
      GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent, 
    ],
  });
const Discord = require('discord.js') // discord.js modülü tanımlıyoruz.
//const client = new Discord.Client() // client tanımalamsı
const { readdirSync } = require('fs'); // tanımlamalar
const { join } = require('path'); // tanımlamalar


  module.exports = client;

require("./events/message.js")
require("./events/ready.js")

client.login(config.token)
```

how can i fix this error?

Comment: What do you mean by _"importing a project"_?

Comment: I put the codes in an infrastructure into my own project

Comment: What version of discord.js do you have installed? `Partials` was introduced in v14, replacing `PartialTypes`.

Comment: ow im really stupid thank you